# How to disable and enable a Jquery click function (using Img id) until an ajax complete in MVC?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

On a page load am loading some data using Ajax.

```
<img src="@Url.Content"~/image/link_1.png")"id="click_1">
<img src="@Url.Content"~/image/link_2.png")"id="click_2">


$("#click_1").click(function(e){

// 

}
$("#click_2").click(function(e){

// 

}
```

In an ajax call  ***beforeSend*** event i have to disable these two click options and on ***complete*** event i want to enable it again.
how to made this possible ? i have tried

```
.removeAttr("onclick");
.[0].onclick = null;
.prop("onclick", false);
```

but doesnt solved my problem.
my Ajax call;

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
         $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'',
                data:{},
                global:false,
                beforeSend:function(){
                   $("#loader").show();
                   $("#click_1").removeAttr("onclick");
                   $("#click_2").removeAttr("onclick");
                },
               success:function(data){
                },
               complete:function(){
                    $("#loader").hide();

                },
              async:true
             });
     });
```

Comment: try this `$("#click_1").off("click")`

Comment: @Narro tried but not worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue simply by changing the CSS property of image tag.
in ajax **beforeSend:**
  `$("#click_1").css("pointer-event","none")`;

and in ajax **complete:**

```
$("#click_1").css("pointer-event","");
```